# How to wrap text using \boxed?

Tags: boxes, wrap, text

I am struggling to get the text to wrap inside the boxed equation. Any help anyone could give me would be greatly appreciated!

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{grffile} %Stops the file name of figures appearing
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}
\usepackage{pifont}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \boxed{H_0 : There\ is\ no\ association\ between\ the\ number\ of\ seasons\ a\ club\ has\ previously\ played\ in\ the\ top \ division\ and\ survival}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\boxed{H_1 : There\ is\ an\ association\ between\ the\ number\ of\ seasons\ a\ club\ has\ previously\ played\ in\ the\ top\ division\ and\ survival}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: surely you don't want _any_ of this text to be in math mode? `There\ is\ no\ association\ betwee....`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.ST](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx), you must familiarize with our format. Blocks of code show better if you indent with four spaces (or select and `Ctrl+K`), this time Torbjørn T did this for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to get a simple box, e.g. the `framed` package and environment. (For fancier stuff, look at `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`.) I wouldn't use an `equation*` for that at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\noindent $H_0$: There is no association between the number of seasons a club has previously played in the top  division and survival
\end{framed}
\begin{framed}
\noindent $H_1$: There is an association between the number of seasons a club has previously played in the top  division and survival
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]